# NHibernate 4.1.1.4000/Oracle 12c - Trouble Saving Entities With "GENERATED ALWAYS" Identity Column

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

Having a bit of a struggle finding the proper mapping incantation for this scenario.

I have an Oracle database with series of tables containing identity columns defined like this:

```
"ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOT NULL ENABLE
```

I have models defined like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public virtual decimal Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }

}
```

And mapped like this:

```
public class MyModelMap : ClassMapping<MyModel> {

    public MyModelMap() {
        Schema("OWNER");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Generator(Generators.SequenceIdentity, gmap => gmap.Params(new {sequence = "MySequenceName" }));
        }); 

        Property(x => x.SomeProperty, map => { map.NotNullable(true); map.Length(2); });

    }
}
```

When I try to do a `Session.Save(myModelObject)' with it mapped this way, NHibernate generates this:

```
INSERT INTO OWNER.MyModel
            (Id,
             SomeProperty)
VALUES      (OWNER.MySequenceName.nextval,
             'AA' /* :p0 */)
returning Id into :nhIdOutParam
```

To which the database responds:

> ERROR: ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column Could not execute command: INSERT INTO...

And that's as close as I've been able to get to INSERTing new records in these tables with NH. I've tried several of the other generators as well. For example, using 
`Generators.Sequence` results in an INSERT like this...

```
INSERT INTO OWNER.MyModel
            (SomeProperty, Id)
VALUES      ('AA' /* :p0 */, 50 /* :p1 */)
returning Id into :nhIdOutParam
```

...with the same resulting error from the database (and the same with Native, Sequence, and EnhancedSequence Generators). The Id is being included in the INSERT each time, either with a concrete value (per the sequence) or a `.nextval` call on the sequence, and the database is, of course, telling me I'm not allowed to do that. I haven't been able to find a way to keep NH from trying to set the Id in Oracle, and thus letting the DB set it on INSERT. I have similar tables in SQL Server with similar mappings, using Identity Generator - NH does NOT attempt to pass an Id for those and they work fine.

**So, how do I tell NHibernate to NOT include the Id column in the INSERT it generates?**

I tried setting `map.Access(Accessor.ReadOnly);` in hopes of preventing that, but, with the exception of the SequenceIdentity Generator, that results in NH failing to produce an INSERT at all with the following complaint:

> {"identifier of an instance of MyModel was altered from 54 to 0"}

(My guess - NH is getting the next Id from the database sequence as expected, but apparently takes issue with the entity Id having the default value of 0. It's accusing me of altering it, but I *feel* innocent.)

I can keep listing all the things I've tried, but hopefully I've provided enough information for someone smarter than me to base some suggestions on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate does not currently [support identity columns with Oracle](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3768).

Use a sequence instead.

Otherwise, try deriving from `Oracle12cDialect`, override `SupportsIdentityColumns` to return `true`, override other identity related properties/methods as suitable for Oracle, configure your application to use your new dialect, map your id as generated with `Identity`, and test that.

See [`Dialect`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Dialect.cs#L808) identity region for details. PR welcome if you can implement the identity support.
On Hibernate side, it looks implemented, see [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/identity/Oracle12cIdentityColumnSupport.java) if this can help you implementing it with NHibernate.

Comment: Not the answer I'd hoped for, but it appears to be the answer nonetheless. I'll see what I can do to put together a PR to address this. At the very least, it will be a learning experience. Thank you!

Comment: I have just check the NHibernate Jira base, there is [a ticket for this: NH-3768](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3768). But no pending PR yet. If you patch NHibernate `Oracle12cDialect`, just follow the [guidelines](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) and your commit and PR would be associated to the Jira.